# Magento2 : Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_mymodule.catalog_category_entity_textarea' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I have created a custom module to create attribute for categories in **Magento 2.2.4**. When I run the **setup upgrade** command then it gave me this error.

```
1146 Table 'magento_mymodule.catalog_category_entity_textarea' doesn't exist
```

Please suggest me if any other way to create category attribute in magento 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can create category custom attribute by adding the following code in the InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\{
    ModuleContextInterface,
    ModuleDataSetupInterface,
    InstallDataInterface
};

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'is_plant', [
            'type'     => 'int',
            'label'    => 'Is this Plant?',
            'input'    => 'boolean',
            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'visible'  => true,
            'default'  => '0',
            'required' => false,
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'Display Settings',
        ]);
    }
}
```

If you want to show in the backend then you have to add this attribute via  ui_component
Create a file in your custom module view/adminhtml/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="display_settings">
        <field name="is_plant">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is this Plant?</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```